# How do I retrieve individual text values when all divs have same class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-tag-manager

I have a block of research site addresses with hyperlinks allowing users to email the research sites directly. Ultimately, I want some sort of jQuery function that returns the street address above whatever email link the user clicked.

Here is the function I'm working with, with the HTML shown below. Every time I click on 'Email this Site' it returns all of the addresses shown on the page. I would like it just to show the address of the site I'm choosing to email however.

```js
$('.doctor-email').click(function(e){
    var address = $('.doctor-address').text();
    console.log(address);
  })
```

```html
<div class="doctor-address">740 South Lindy Street<br>J401<br>Burbank,&nbsp;CA&nbsp;40536</div>
        <div class="doctor-directions">
          <a href="javascript: void(0);" onclick="javascript: ViewMap('https://maps.google.com/?daddr=740+South+Limestone+Street%2c+Lexington%2c+KY+40536');">
            Get Directions
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-6">
        <p class="doctor-email">
          <a href="javascript: ContactSite('5859')">
            Email this site
          </a>
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-10 col-sm-9">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-6">
        <div class="doctor-address">800 South West Street<br>J401<br>Lexington,&nbsp;KY&nbsp;40536</div>
        <div class="doctor-directions">
          <a href="javascript: void(0);" onclick="javascript: ViewMap('https://maps.google.com/?daddr=800+South+West+Street%2c+Chicago%2c+IL+40536');">
            Get Directions
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-6">
        <p class="doctor-email">
          <a href="javascript: ContactSite('5859')">
            Email this site
          </a>
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
  <div class="col-xs-10 col-sm-9">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-6">
        <div class="doctor-address">900 Delavan Street<br>J401<br>Buffalo,&nbsp;NY&nbsp;40536</div>
        <div class="doctor-directions">
          <a href="javascript: void(0);" onclick="javascript: ViewMap('https://maps.google.com/?daddr=900+Delavan+Street%2c+Chicago%2c+IL+40536');">
            Get Directions
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-6">
        <p class="doctor-email">
          <a href="javascript: ContactSite('5859')">
            Email this site
          </a>
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
```

I am very new to javascript, so any and all feedback is welcome.

Thanks!
Brett

Comment: Unfortunately not that I've been able to find. To give you a little background, I did not build this site, instead I'm going to use the function in a google tag manager tag to fire events to Google Analytics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```
$('.doctor-email').click(function(e){
    //go up to the contextual row, and then find the nested address
    var address = $(this).closest('.row').find('.doctor-address').text();
    console.log(address);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Just replace the selector with `this` and it should create a JQuery object referencing the item you have clicked.

UPDATED:

```js
$('.doctor-email').click(function(e){
    var address = $(this).parents(".row").find(".doctor-address").text();
    console.log(address);
})
```

```html
<div class="doctor-address">740 South Lindy Street<br>J401<br>Burbank,&nbsp;CA&nbsp;40536</div>
        <div class="doctor-directions">
          <a href="javascript: void(0);" onclick="javascript: ViewMap('https://maps.google.com/?daddr=740+South+Limestone+Street%2c+Lexington%2c+KY+40536');">
            Get Directions
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-6">
        <p class="doctor-email">
          <a href="javascript: ContactSite('5859')">
            Email this site
          </a>
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-10 col-sm-9">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-6">
        <div class="doctor-address">800 South West Street<br>J401<br>Lexington,&nbsp;KY&nbsp;40536</div>
        <div class="doctor-directions">
          <a href="javascript: void(0);" onclick="javascript: ViewMap('https://maps.google.com/?daddr=800+South+West+Street%2c+Chicago%2c+IL+40536');">
            Get Directions
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-6">
        <p class="doctor-email">
          <a href="javascript: ContactSite('5859')">
            Email this site
          </a>
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
  <div class="col-xs-10 col-sm-9">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-6">
        <div class="doctor-address">900 Delavan Street<br>J401<br>Buffalo,&nbsp;NY&nbsp;40536</div>
        <div class="doctor-directions">
          <a href="javascript: void(0);" onclick="javascript: ViewMap('https://maps.google.com/?daddr=900+Delavan+Street%2c+Chicago%2c+IL+40536');">
            Get Directions
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-6">
        <p class="doctor-email">
          <a href="javascript: ContactSite('5859')">
            Email this site
          </a>
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! I just tried your suggestion and the console log returns "Email This Site." I'm trying to get it to return the actual address associated with whatever 'email-this-site' link they clicked. For instance, if they click 'email this site' in the third div, I'd like the console to return '900 Delavan street, J401, Buffalo, NY'

Comment: Oh I see, I updated my answer as my method is slightly different from the top answer

Answer (score 0):

To access individual address, you should go with id.

Other way is as Mike suggested from the current context use jQuery `prev()` function to get the text of address.

Refer:[prev()](https://api.jquery.com/prev/)